# Export images with Laravel-Excel

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-excel

my Code Here is Exporting Images For Products Table but it exported in this format https://prnt.sc/109zsm6 i think image not setting for column value or not overriding

in column there is image and text from $product->image how should print image in right way

```
 public function registerEvents(): array
    {

        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                //Freeze frist row
                $event->sheet->freezePane('A2', 'A2');

                $products = Product::limit(10)->get();
                //Set row height
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) //iterate based on row count
                {
                    $event->sheet->getRowDimension('E' . +$i)->setRowHeight(60);
                }

                $loop = 1;
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    $drawing = new Drawing();
                    $drawing->setName('image');
                    $drawing->setDescription('image');
                    $drawing->setPath(public_path($product->image));
                    $drawing->setHeight(70);
                    $drawing->setOffsetX(5);
                    $drawing->setOffsetY(5);
                    $drawing->setCoordinates('E' . $loop);
                    $drawing->setWorksheet($event->sheet->getDelegate());
                    $loop++;
                }
            },
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @var product $product
     */
    public function map($product): array
    {
        return [
            $product->id,
            $product->category_id,
            $product->category_name,
            $product->name,
            $product->image,
            $product->created_at,
            $product->updated_at,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: did you add `implements WithDrawings` ? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/drawings.html

Comment: yes i  implemented WithDrawings

Comment: the images is in exported file but it's not fixed in column

Comment: @KamleshPaul https://prnt.sc/10a18mn

Comment: you need to adjust row height https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/sizing.html#set-row-height

Comment: and how to hide the text or override images to text

Comment: remove this may be `$product->name,`

Comment: @KamleshPaul https://prnt.sc/10a1kbw next column data go to image column and image take about 4 columns in hight hot to make image in one column and take column value because next columns got to image if i delete image link